# How to pass object from view to the java-function?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a jsp-page

```
<%@page import="org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView"%>
  <%@page import="mvc3.helpers.Utils"%>
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
  <%@ page session="false" %>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>View Topic</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <fieldset>
       <legend>${topic.getName()}</legend>
       <div class="display-label-field"><b>Content:</b>${topic.getText()}</div>
       <div class="display-label-field"><b>Comments count:</b>${topic.getCommentsCount()}</div>
       <div class="display-label-field"><b>Last time updated:</b>${topic.getTimeLastUpdated()}</div>

  </fieldset>

  <p>
    <%=Utils.actionLink("Comment Topic", "Topic", "AddComment", Integer.toString( topic.getId() ) ) %>
    <%=Utils.actionLink("Back to Topic List", "", "home", null)%>
  </p>
```

The problem is, that **${topic.getName()}** works fine, but **<%=Utils.actionLink("Comment Topic", "Topic", "AddComment", Integer.toString( topic.getId() ) ) %>** causes the *topic cannot be resolved* error. How can I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set attribute topic in request then do

```
Integer.toString( ((Topic)request.getAttribute("topic")).getId())
```

Comment: Almost correct. We need to use full type declaration **mvc3.model.Topic** instead of **Topic**

Comment: Or you could do `<@page import="..."/>`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't we access getId with EL? Something like below?

```
Integer.toString( ${topic.getId()})
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `"topic"` has not been set for your view model. In your controller you will need something like:

```
myModelData.put("topic", topicId);
```